# Oracle SQL(Plus) ORDER BY - Invalid Identifier (Nested Subquery)

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, subquery

First off - already looked at a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732019/invalid-identifier-error-on-field-created-with-select-statement), but it did not exactly pertain to my problem.

Secondly, this is a homework assignment, but the question pertains to SQL syntax - I already wrote the query and the results are as expected, just unordered.

Thirdly, I believe I know why the error is occurring - the sub-quer(y)(ies) are affecting the ordering of the outer query (maybe), and thus an order cannot be created based on the way that the queries are nested.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.ssn, E.lname
FROM employee E, works_on W
WHERE E.ssn = W.essn AND
W.pno NOT IN
    (SELECT P.pnumber
    FROM project P
    WHERE P.plocation = 'Houston')
    MINUS
    (SELECT E.ssn, E.lname
    FROM employee E, works_on W, project P
    WHERE E.ssn = W.essn AND
    W.pno = P.pnumber AND
    P.plocation = 'Houston')
ORDER BY E.lname;
```

---

```
SSN       LNAME                                                                 
--------- ---------------                                                       
123456789 Smith                                                                 
453453453 English                                                               
987987987 Jabbar                                                                
999887777 Zelaya
```

Now if I remove `ORDER BY E.lname` from the end of the query, it runs fine. Otherwise, I get an "invalid identifier" error. I assume this is because `E.lname` means nothing at that point in the query.

So my question is... how can I "wrap" the queries in such a way (as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732019/invalid-identifier-error-on-field-created-with-select-statement)) that I can sort the results by `E.lname`?

I've already tried wrapping it in what feels like over 9,000 ways, but I haven't found a solution that works. I'm also new to SQL, so I doubt that I could change the structure of the query to give me the same results using any amount of sub-queries less than what I currently have.

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to help me out, much appreciated! If it is necessary to provide the table creation code, let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you tried 9000 ways but how about

```
SELECT ssn,lname from
(
SELECT DISTINCT E.ssn, E.lname
FROM employee E, works_on W
WHERE E.ssn = W.essn AND
W.pno NOT IN
    (SELECT P.pnumber
    FROM project P
    WHERE P.plocation = 'Houston')
    MINUS
    (SELECT E.ssn, E.lname
    FROM employee E, works_on W, project P
    WHERE E.ssn = W.essn AND
    W.pno = P.pnumber AND
    P.plocation = 'Houston')
)
ORDER BY lname;
```

Or using ordinal notation,

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.ssn, E.lname
FROM employee E, works_on W
WHERE E.ssn = W.essn AND
W.pno NOT IN
    (SELECT P.pnumber
    FROM project P
    WHERE P.plocation = 'Houston')
    MINUS
    SELECT E.ssn, E.lname
    FROM employee E, works_on W, project P
    WHERE E.ssn = W.essn AND
    W.pno = P.pnumber AND
    P.plocation = 'Houston'

ORDER BY 2;
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I can't test it out at the moment because SSH isn't being cooperative at the moment. I understand the idea though. Since my original query (as a whole) was returning two attributes, I would want to wrap the whole thing (again). I see that in both examples, and I understand the ordinal notation as well. However, the question that still bothers me is, why is this necessary? Still new to SQL, so I don't understand the underlying process that disallows ordering with nested sub-queries (something to do with attributes being lost in execution?).

Comment: Don't take what I wrote for granted. I haven't tested it either but those were based on my intuition. I would rather you try them out and confirm they work and then we will try to figure out the 'why'.

Comment: They do indeed work, thanks :) So what might your thoughts be as to why "wrapping" the query as a whole allowed for sorting on the second attribute `E.lname`?

Comment: I think you figured it out correctly. You want to apply your sort on a set which is result of set1 minus set2. But at the time of 'order by', there is really no 'E' anymore. if you have programming experience, think of E as a local variable within a function. You are trying to refer to E outside its scope basically. The changes we made avoid trying to refer to E. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Ahhh yeah that makes perfect sense! I've pretty much forgotten all of my previous knowledge of set operations, and order of operations in general. Combine that with my lack of knowledge of SQL syntax and the result is me needing to post a question that has a simple answer on SO! But I completely understand the scoping issue. I figured that was the problem from the start, but I had no clue how to give SQL the 'wrapper' that it wanted in order to sort the attributes. In any case, I know better now thanks to you. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to remove any employee who works on a project in Houston?  Then this should work using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.ssn, E.lname
FROM employee E
   INNER JOIN works_on W 
       ON E.ssn = W.essn AND
   LEFT JOIN project P 
       ON w.pno = p.pnumber AND P.plocation = 'Houston'
WHERE p.pnumber IS NULL
ORDER BY E.lname
```

Comment: Essentially, yes. If an employee works on ANY project (they work on multiple, which is W.pno and P.pnumber) that is located in Houston, then they should NOT be returned in the results. We haven't really discussed inner/outer/left(/right?) joins yet, so I would refrain from using them. Though it is probably better practice, reducing the amount of work done and all, my database is so small that there would be almost zero difference in the performance of the query. Thank you for your suggestion though, I'll study it up!